# Powershell compare files in 2 locations and return files with a newer timestamp

Tags: powershell, file, datetime, compare

I want to compare two directories $source and $destination and find any files that are in both but have a later timestamp in $destination.  Including files in any subdirectories.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49838139/how-to-copy-only-new-files-from-one-folder-to-another-with-powershell?adlt=strict)  but that returns me files that are newer in the source as well.(I changed the SideIndicator from '=>'  to '<=' for my test but still no luck.

I only want the files that are more recent in the destination.
e.g for these 2 source and dest dirs I would want returned Charles.txt and Ernie.txt.

[image: Source Dir]
[image: Dest Dir]

Can it be done with Compare-Object somehow?

Many thanks

Comment: Do you want to compare them by name alone, or by relative path?

Comment: There shouldnt be any files with same names in any subdirectories but if there was then yes by relative path I guess.  
So if there was ay a subdirectory DirOne\alan.text in both source and dest then if the alan.txt in dest\DirOne\Alan.txt was newer than source\DirOne\alan.txt Id want to know.